# Storing data from a data frame inside a databricks spark notebook to an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

I have a Dataframe in my python code which runs in an databricks notebook, which is filled with data i get from the Spotify API. I store this Data i get from the api into a data frame.
Now i want to bring this data to AWS S3. I tried `dbutils.fs.put` and boto3 `s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object` but since now managed only to read from my S3 bucket, i always face problems, when i am trying to write someting to it. I don't know how to store the data from the data frame. I thought about saving it as csv to the databricks file store and uploading it from there. But when i try to upload a file i don't know how to set the path right.

With boto3 i tried

```
data = open('/dbfs:/FileStore/tables/example.csv', 'rb')

s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/example.csv', Body=data)
```

but got the following error:
FileNotFoundError:                         Traceback (most recent call last)

> in 
> ----> 1 data = open('/dbfs:/FileStore/tables/example.csv', 'rb')
> 2
> 3 s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).put_object(Key='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/example.csv',
> Body=data)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/dbfs:/FileStore/tables/example.csv'

With dbutils i tried:

```
dbutils.fs.put(s"/mnt/$s3data", "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/example.csv")
```

but got:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What i am trying is, to estabish a datapipeline where i can load the data from Spotify, check it (which i have already implemented) and store it to S3, to use it later in a different notebook to do some evaluations.

Comment: you can use the dataframewriter to save the data to s3 or on databricks dbfs.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is, when i am using `df.write("destiantionpath")' i get an error message "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write' "

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write data directly to S3 from your Spark pipeline, no need to store it first to DBFS.  There are two approaches:

1. Store data directly using the `s3://bucket.../path...` as argument to `save`
2. Mount your S3 bucket as DBFS, and point to that location in `save`

In your case, Boto3 doesn't work because you're using `dbfs:/...` syntax that isn't understood by Boto3 that expects the local file.  You can still workaround it by replacing `dbfs:/` with `/dbfs/` - that's so-called FUSE mount...

`dbutils.fs.put` is used to put content that should be the second argument into the given file, not copy the file - for that you can use `dbutils.fs.cp` command.

But I recommend to use one of the two approaches described at beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But i don't quite get it how to do it. when i try to take my Dataframe `df.save("s3:/myBucketName/")` i get the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'save' "  and when i try to use `df.write.csv("s3:/myBucketName/")` i get the same thing "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write' "

Comment: you need to do `df.write.format("...").mode("append").save(...)` see Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

Comment: you already have the Pandas dataframe, not Spark dataframe... change name of Pandas dataframe to something like `pdf` to avoid redefinition